# My internal multilingual link point in wrong direction

Tags: drupal, multilingual

Have some serious problem with links behaviour in my multilingual site (English (en) and Swedish (sv)). The default languages is English.
I have some nodes with a summery. In the summery I have internal links to my Swedish content. To link to page3 I use sv/page3.
I make a view with the summaries filtered on the language.
If I place this view as a front page all works fine but if I link the view from a translated Menu-link the will be sv/sv/page3.

Hope for help

Answer (score 1):

Will adding slash sign at beginning help? Try using root relative paths instead of relative paths. So don't use `sv/page3`, but instead use `/sv/page3`

Comment: You are welcome. It's important to understand how web browser is building relative links. If link is relative browser just adds link path to currently displayed path and lead you to that url when link is clicked. But if link is root relative it ignores current page path.